# 503 timeout on PHP 5.6.31

Tags: php, apache, timeout

I have two and more servers running PHP 5.4.45 with same scripts and none of them are doing any issue when calling a script that requires more than 60 seconds to finish.

However, a new server having PHP 5.6.31 is returning 503 timeout, when I run the same script. I tried everything found on the internet from keepAlive to timeout in httpd.conf and in php.ini, I already have

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 5);
```

Inside the code and all that. Same script same everything just different PHP version on 5.4.45 it works perfectly while on 5.6.31 I always get timeout unless when the full script executes in less than 60 seconds [I don't know where that limit comes from eventhough I changed anything related to 60 from the httpd.conf and php.ini) .

Kindly can you help me troubleshoot.

Comment: `ini_set('max_execution_time', 5);` is 5 seconds.

Comment: I've actually placed it as 0 not 5 and still the same result